# R: varying-coefficient GAMM models in mgcv - extracting 'by' variable coefficients?

Tags: r, hierarchy, gam, mgcv

I am creating a varying-coefficient GAMM using 'mgcv' in R with a continuous 'by' variable by using the `by` setting. However, I am having difficulty in locating the parameter estimate of the effect of the 'by' variable. In this example we determine the spatially-dependent effect of temperature `t` on sole eggs (i.e. how the linear effect of temperature on sole eggs changes across space):

```
require(mgcv)
require(gamair)
data(sole)
b = gam(eggs ~ s(la,lo) + s(la,lo, by = t), data = sole)
```

We can then plot the predicted effects of `s(la,lo, by = t)` against the predictor `t`:

```
pred <- predict(b, type = "terms", se.fit =T)
by.variable.prediction <- pred[[1]][,2]
plot(x= sole$t, y = by.variable.prediction)
```

However, I can't find a listing/function with the parameter estimates of the 'by' variable `t` for each sampling location. `summary()`, `coef()`, and `predict()` do not give you the parameter estimates.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at `?mgcv::s`, specifically the description of `by`. If `t` is numeric then the value of `t` multiplies the smooth. If `t` is a factor then there is a separate smooth for each level of the factor. If you want to extract the smooths themselves (I wouldn't recommend it... don't see what use they'd be), [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15584541/903061).

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I looked around `mgcv::s` and it doesn't really give you much. With a numeric `t` predictor, in my case, we are assuming a linear relationship who's slope could change across `la,lo`, so for each unique `la,lo` we get a specific slope, correct? Then I should be able to find the magnitude and direction of that slope somewhere, it's just being elusive :). I don't want to extract the smooths, just want to plot that variable-coefficient term using those slopes.

Comment: For each `la` and `lo`, there is a smoothed value that gets multiplied by `t`. There isn't anything else. This is what the documentation states. You can interpret `t` as the "slope" of the smoothed `la,lo` variable, or you can interpret the `la,lo` smooth as the slope of `t`.

Comment: Smoothing is done with multiplicative constants - it doesn't make sense to fit an additional parameter to multiply a smooth by, because any such value can be directly incorporated into the smooth.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! That makes sense. Would you know of any resources for plotting the things? I'm trying for something similar to: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1890/09-1129.1/abstract

Comment: I don't have access to that article. `mgcv` has nice plotting built in. I'd highly recommend [Simon Wood's book on GAMs](http://www.amazon.com/Generalized-Additive-Models-Introduction-Statistical/dp/1584884746).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the Wood 2006 book doesn't go into much detail on these models. If your are interested the article for free is at [NOAA's site](http://www.sefsc.noaa.gov/FEBpub/Bartolino_etal_2011_Ecology.pdf). Figure 4 is the one that plots a similar model.

Answer (score 0):

So the coefficient for the variable `t` is the value where `t` is equal to 1, conditional on the latitude and longitude.  So one way to get the coefficient/parameter estimate for t at each latitude and longitude is to construct your own dataframe with a range of latitude/longitude combinations with `t=1` and run predict.gam on that (rather than running predict.gam on the data used the fit the model, as you have done).  So:

```
preddf <- expand.grid(list(la=seq(min(sole$la), max(sole$la), length.out=100),
                           lo=seq(min(sole$lo), max(sole$lo), length.out=100),
                           t=1))

preddf$parameter <- predict(b, preddf, type="response")
```

And then if you want to visualize this coefficient over space, you could graph it with ggplot2.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(preddf) + 
  geom_tile(aes(x=lo, y=la, fill=parameter))
```