# how the lpmatrix in GAM model is calculated?

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

we could get

```r
Xp <- predict(mod, newdata = my_new_data, type = 'lpmatrix')
```

in `{mgcv}` package.

I am wondering how `Xp` is being calculated? The definition is `X_p` is the model matrix where spline covariates `s(x)` have been replaced by the values of the basis functions `b_j(x)` evaluated at the respective covariate `x`.

There are some relevent links [How to extract fitted splines from a GAM (`mgcv::gam`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584541/how-to-extract-fitted-splines-from-a-gam-mgcvgam)
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406566/using-gam-outside-statistical-modelling-software-in-datatabase-outside-r
while did not explain how the `Xp` is extracted.